# System.Int32[] showing in textboxes in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm working in Visual Basic. I'm passing integers to a label through a function but then the label displays the value it shows `System.Int32[]` and no error, when you click 'done' it saves and the save files shows the right number. If you could give me some advice and help it would be appreciated, thank you

```
'function for adding 1 point to your selected level.
Private Function SkillPoints(IntSkill)
        'checks if you have enough level points
        If IntLevel > 0 Then
            'adds 1 point to the selected skill and minuses 1 from Intlevel
            Intskillpoints(IntSkill) += 1
            IntLevel -= 1
            LblLvlPoints.Text = IntLevel
        Else
            MsgBox("You have run out of skill points.")
        End If
        ' returns the value to be shown in the label
        Return Intskillpoints
    End Function


    Private Sub BtnAtkPlus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAtkPlus.Click
    'when you click the button it sets the lbl to the result of the function.
        LblAttackPoints.Text = SkillPoints(0).ToString
    End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to `Return Intskillpoints(IntSkill)` instead?

Comment: You should really enable Option Strict

Comment: @MikeChristensen post you answer as a separate answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone getting this issue, you have more than likely missed the arrays Index. in my case i didn't return an array index but the actual array like this:

```
Return Intskillpoints
```

this way return the entire array.
but it should be:

```
Return Intskillpoints(IntSkill)
```

this way return a value from the array and not the entire array.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will point out some coding errors you have there.

You need to declare the type of the variable passed to the function and its return value:

```
Private Function SkillPoints(IntSkill As Integer) As Integer()
```

You should convert the Integer to a String to use it as Text:

```
LblLvlPoints.Text = IntLevel.ToString()
```

P.S. It's "Visual Basic", not "Visual Basics".

P.P.S. The reason the label shows `System.Int32[]` is that somehow you've used `.ToString()` on an array (it uses `[]` instead of `()` to show it's an array) so you need to track down how you are giving it an array instead of a scalar. It might be that that problem is fixed when you have gone through all the corrections that enabling Option Strict On points out for you.

Comment: I have no idea what he is trying to accomplish, but the type name display comes from `SkillPoints(0).ToString` where skillpoints is the function returning an array.  he may want to display the array contents based on `...passing integers to a label through a function`

Comment: @Plutonix The OP didn't say *which* label is displaying `System.Int32[]`. Until the types are fixed, I think we are on a mystery trail trying to work out the fundamental problem ;) Then we can work on why functions with side-effects are not such a good idea.

Comment: ...or maybe it is a bug in Visual Basics

Comment: i found the problem. the return statement is an array and i forgot to add the (intskill) :/ nooby mistake. thanks you for the help though